# How to reference a file relative to the original script?

Tags: python, module, path, relative-path

I wrote my own module (i.e. my_module.py). This is accessing a database located in the same directory by just opening it with the path 'database.db'. But when I am using my module, the 'database.db' references the directory im using my module in.

For example I have following directory structur:

```
/main
  /my_module
    my_module.py
    database.db
  script.py
```

So if im now directly using 'database.db' in my_module.py it points towards `/main/my_module/database.db`.
But if I am using my_module inside script.py it points towards `/main/database.db` which causes an error.

So my question is: How is it possible to have a path pointing relatively to the modules script `my_module.py`? (so I can use it in any place) Thanks a lot for answers!

Answer (score 0):

From `script.py` try using `os.path` to get the script directory.  Then you can create a relative path to the database file:

```
import os
maindir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
my_module_dir = os.path.join(maindir, 'my_module')
db_path = os.path.join(my_module_dir, 'database.db')
```

Comment: What is `os.path.dirname(__file__)` exactly returning?

Comment: `__file__` contains the path to whatever source file it appears in.  `dirname(__file__)` is the folder containing the source file.  For example if `__file__` appears in `<path_to>/script.py` it will evaluate to `<path_to>/script.py` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!